# How to execute UI tests for a Dynamic Feature Module via Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, dynamic-feature-module

I have a regular `:app` module and a DFM `:feature`.

I place the tests for the DFM in `androidTest` source set inside `:feature`.

When I try to launch the test using run configuration created by Android Studio it silently fails with `Test framework quit unexpectedly`.

If I launch the test through the terminal with the command displayed by Android Studio in `Run` tab I will see:

```sh
$ adb shell am instrument -w -m    -e debug false -e class 'com.amazing.feature.AmazingTest' com.amazing.application.test/com.amazing.feature.TestRunner
...
Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.amazing.application.test/com.amazing.feature.TestRunner}
```

Which is not surprising, since the path to the runner is different:

```sh
$ adb shell pm list instrumentation
instrumentation:com.amazing.feature.test/com.amazing.feature.TestRunner (target=com.amazing.application)
```

The test works if I use that instrumentation on the commandline.

Is there a way to teach Android Studio do that?

Comment: Which AS version are you using? Looks like some cache is corrupted, which links to the wrong runner path. Maybe some package renaming, an update, or copy/pasting of folders could have caused that.  Have you created the dynamic feature module via "Create New Module" or in any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. Turns out gradle creates a wrong `targetPackage` in the <instrumentation> tag in the dynamic feature module's `AndroidManifest.xml` of the androidTest APK. You can fix this by setting the `testApplicationId` in the module's build.gradle defaultConfig.

```
defaultConfig {    
    testApplicationId 'com.amazing.feature.test' // Set the test package here!
    testInstrumentationRunner 'com.amazing.feature.TestRunner'
    [...]
}
```

[More documentation on this on developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/test#configure_instrumentation_manifest_settings).

Answer (score 3):

I got this issue as well, just after upgrading to AGP 7 and the latest Android Studio. In my case it was a bit different, I have the same repository checked out twice, so work on 2 branches simultaneously. In my case, it happened that one branch + android studio instance would work, it did select the correct TestRunner, and the other instance did not work. This lead me to the simple solution of:

1. Build -> Clean Project
2. Remove any remaining build folders (was just 1 for me)

Then retry and it did select the correct TestRunner.
Other things ive tried, of which I do not know whether or not they helped, are the following:

- Make sure I use Java 11 (since i'm on AGP 7)

  - `Project Structure` -> `Gradle settings` -> `Gradle JDK` should be something like 11
- Disable the experimental feature `Do not build Gradle task list during Gradle sync` (automatically enabled on Android Studio Arctic Fox)